# Show that interval $[0, 1]$ is not compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ with lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My try: let's take an open cover $C$ of $I = [0, 1]$ as follows:

$C = \{[0, \frac{n}{n + 1})\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cup [1, 2)$

then we obviously can't get a finite subcover of $C$, hence $[0, 1]$ is not compact.

My other try: a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, $[0, 1]$ is bounded, so we need to show that it is open. But $I^C = \mathbb{R}/I = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) = (\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}[-n, 0))\cup(\bigcup_{m = 1}^{\infty}[1 + \frac{1}{m}, m + 2))$,

so I wrote $I^C$ as union of open sets, hence it is open and then $I$ is closed, but that would mean it is compact.

My question is, where is the mistake in my second try? (I'm quite sure the first one is fine)

Comment: Does closed and bounded imply compact in your topology?

Comment: Oh, so that's the problem, that it is not a global property for any topological space, right? So at least I found a counterexample for that, which should be useful later.

Comment: Correct, that only applies to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The standard topology is so "nice" it allows us a very easy way to see compactness--an intuition that doesn't apply to other topologies.  Another large counterexample is in an infinite dimensional normed vector space, the closed unit ball is never compact (even though it's clearly closed and bounded).

Comment: Okay, thank you. You can also write it as an answer, so I can mark it answered (don't know if it is required or no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed and bounded does not imply compact in the lower limit topology.  See the Wikipedia article for precisely which sets are compact (countably many elements).